# how to write aggregate conditional SQL query to get individual column counts and total counts by passing date arguments

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I did some thing like this:

```
with q1 as 
( 
  select x, count(*) as A from T1 where .. condition group by x
 ),
q2 as ( select x, count(*) AS B  from T2 where .. condition group by x),
q3 as ( select x, count(*) AS C from T3 where .. condition group by x),
Q4 AS ( select x, count(*) AS D from T4 where .. condition group by x)

SELECT Q1.X, Q1.A, Q2.B, Q3.C, Q4.D FROM Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4
```

I only get blank results.. also i'm passing date as input arguments for each select. 
column x exists in 4 different tables. All i have to do is show the count of x from each table for a particular date range.

Comment: Can you post the actual query in a minimal reducible example?

Comment: Execute each of the CTEs. Do they all return results individually?

Comment: @forpas Yes they do. q3 and q4 have no counts and they come blank. i have used NVL but still all the results go blank. just the column names are displayed. but q1 and q2 together result 500 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` and then `conditional aggregation` as following:

```
Select x, 
       Coalesce(sum(case when tab ='Q1' then cnt end),0) As a,
       Coalesce(Sum(case when tab ='Q2' then cnt end),0) As b,
       Coalesce(Sum(case when tab ='Q3' then cnt end),0) As c,
       Coalesce(Sum(case when tab ='Q4' then cnt end),0) As d
From
     (Select 'Q1' as tab, x, count(*) cnt from t1 Where ... group by x
      Union all
      Select 'Q2' as tab, x, count(*) from t2 Where ... group by x
      Union all
      Select 'Q3' as tab, x, count(*) from t3 Where ... group by x
      Union all
      Select 'Q4' as tab, x, count(*) from t4  Where ... group by x)
Group by x;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi Tejash, this got little more complex. i have to get the counts of an event occurring at different locations but the location column exists only in one of the tables and all the tables are connected by a primary key column X.

Answer (score 0):

`Conditional Aggregation` can be used through `JOIN` Clauses by `x` columns which are common in name :

```
select t1.x, 
       count(case when t1.y=1 then 1 end ) as A,
       count(case when t2.z=0 then 1 end ) as B,
       count(case when t3.a=0 then 1 end ) as C,
       count(case when t4.b=0 then 1 end ) as D
  from t1
  join t2 on t2.x = t1.x
  join t3 on t3.x = t1.x
  join t4 on t4.x = t1.x
 group by t1.x
```

Conditions in `WHERE` Clauses are assumed to be `t1.y=1`, `t2.z`, `t3.a`, `t4.b` respectively.

Comment: I get only 0's for all the results using this.

Comment: please share an explicit sample data containing the desired result @sree .